# how to add general serial number and header in table

Tags: r

I want to add serial number and header in table and going forward will convert it into function so serial number should be by default and for header it should be as input parameter.

```
library(tibble)
df <- mtcars %>%
  rownames_to_column(var="carnames") 
df <- df[,c(1:2)] %>% as.data.frame()
names(df[1]) <-  "Names"
```

Comment: Use `dput(df)` is better than image.

Comment: can you explain what you want to do with `names(df[1]) <-  "Names"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want the original column names to be a new row, you will have to first convert the `mpg` column into a `character` variable:

```
library(dplyr)
df = mtcars %>% 
        rownames_to_column("carnames") %>% 
        select(1:2) %>% 
        mutate(mpg = as.character(mpg)) %>% 
        add_row(carnames = "carnames", mpg = "mpg", .before = 1) %>% 
        rename("Cartypes" = carnames, "Rank" = mpg)
```

Output:

```
> df %>% as_tibble()
# A tibble: 33 x 2
   Cartypes          Rank 
   <chr>             <chr>
 1 carnames          mpg  
 2 Mazda RX4         21   
 3 Mazda RX4 Wag     21   
 4 Datsun 710        22.8 
 5 Hornet 4 Drive    21.4 
 6 Hornet Sportabout 18.7 
 7 Valiant           18.1 
 8 Duster 360        14.3 
 9 Merc 240D         24.4 
10 Merc 230          22.8 
# ... with 23 more rows
```

Comment: how can i convert it into flextable, the output i want is flex table

Comment: @str_rst I would suggest you to open a new question (if no one ever asked the same question before) rather than adding questions on top of the original questions. :)